# Does trigger used custom Sobject for one app license?

Tags: licenses

We have some users holding one app license which gives them access to only 10 custom SObjects.

So suppose they have access to create and update SObject A, which when saving them, fires the trigger which needs to lookup data from SObject B. But those users don't need to see the B SObject records at all. Does SObject B still counts as one SObject in this user's license situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all licenses that have this restriction, the limitation is contractual, not technical. Salesforce doesn't monitor whether or not you go over this limit. I doubt that contractually they would enforce this for an object that the users aren't directly accessing.

See [sfdcfox's answer about this:](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173401/about-the-10-custom-objects-limitation-for-community-licenses)

> There are no technical restraints regarding the ten object limit. This is actually mentioned in the documentation somewhere. However, if salesforce.com finds out (however that may be), you would be in violation of your contract and at risk for contractual breach.
>
> In theory, this means you'd be forced to pay for the more expensive
>   licenses that you would have paid for if you'd been upfront about
>   needing more than 10 custom objects to begin with, backdated to the
>   point where the breach of contract occurred.
>
> As long as the users can only view data from ten different custom
>   objects, they should be fine under the contract. **For example, it would
>   be particularly cumbersome if you couldn't write a trigger to update
>   an 11th object they don't have access to when the trigger does so for
>   users not under the 10 object limit.**

Comment: I had a feeling this question was familiar.